# How to create a textView in ruby motion?

Tags: rubymotion

Im just getting started in RubyMotion with a history in Rails.  I have a simple app with two views.  The first view is a tableView that lists an array of 'categories'.  Each category has a detail view.  I originally set up the detail view to also be a tableView, but am changing to UILabel since I only have a small paragraph of static text for each category.  I looked in to using a one row table in the detail and changing the cells height with content, but decided since I will only ever need one cell...it probably was improper use of a table and better use of UILabel (which as far as I can tell is for static text...not just a 'label').  Opinions or ideas on this are very welcome.

## category_view_controller.rb

So, in my existing category_view_controller I have the following method that pushes the details view controller when a row is selected from the list of categories in the category view controller.  As, of now I am creating my categories with their attributes (label and description) statically in app_deligate.rb.  This works fine in the sim.

```
   def tableView(tableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath)

     case indexPath.section
      when 0
       cat, label, desc = Categories.categories_list[indexPath.row]
       detailsVC = DetailViewController.alloc.initWithStyle(UITableViewStyleGrouped,        category:cat, label:label, description:desc)
       navigationController.pushViewController(detailsVC, animated:true)
     end

    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated:true)
  end
```

## DetailViewController.rb.

This controller inherits from UITableViewController.  The code below is already modified to get rid of the tableView...which is why there is no table (you can see where I have started changing to a UILabel).  This loads fine too with a simple white label that includes the detail text I set in the add_deligate file.

```
class DetailViewController < UITableViewController

 def initWithStyle(style, category:cat, label:label, description:desc)
   initWithStyle(style)
   @category = cat
   @description = desc
   @label_text = label
   self
 end


 def viewDidLoad
   super
   self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor

   @label = UILabel.alloc.initWithFrame([[20, 50], [280, 80]]).tap do |label|
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.text = @description
    label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.sizeToFit
    label.textColor = UIColor.colorWithHue(0.0, saturation:0.0, brightness:0.40, alpha:1.0)
    self.view.addSubview(label)
  end
 end  
end
```

## My confusion

I dont know how to go about removing the tableView and just using simple static text through UILabel.  Or, maybe there is yet a better way.

I know I need to change this line in the categories_views_controller that calls the details_view_controller.  This line is still referencing UITableViewStyleGrouped...and should't be since there is no table to style.

```
detailsVC = DetailViewController.alloc.initWithStyle(UITableViewStyleGrouped, category:cat, label:label, description:desc)
```

I tried simply removing 'initWithStyle...but, this breaks the app.

```
detailsVC = DetailViewController.alloc.init(category:cat, label:label, description:desc)
```

I also need the details_view_controller to NOT inherit from < UITableViewController.  This seems as easy as just removing or changing the inheritance.  I tried...but, this breaks the app.  I suspect either of these might work once I correctly remove the 'UITableViewStyleGrouped' from the details call in the categories_view_controller.

```
  class DetailViewController
```

and

```
 class DetailViewController < UIViewController
```

Also, when I set a background color in the viewDidLoad method inside the details_view_controller it does not have any effect.  Not sure why.

```
 self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor
```

So, to recap.  root view is a tableView of static categories and each category has a detail view.  The detail view is loaded when a category in the list is tapped.  The details view is a simple view with a UILabel element displaying that categories detailed description.

I hoping someone can point me in the direction of learning motion and making this code work as intended.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a lot of background reading to do. Not a problem -- we were all there at one point. But the issues you're running into appear to be a general lack of familiarity with Cocoa Touch.

I would recommend reading the official Apple guides, including the View Controller ones.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html

If you'd rather just start coding, ProMotion is going to be your best friend.

https://github.com/clearsightstudio/ProMotion

ProMotion abstracts away a lot of the messy Objective-C and allows you to just open and close screens with simple commands.

```
class AppDelegate < ProMotion::AppDelegateParent
  def on_load
    open ListScreen.new(nav_bar: true)
  end
end

class ListScreen < ProMotion::TableScreen
  def table_data
    [{
      title: "",
      cells: [{
        title: "Cell 1",
        action: :selected_cell,
        arguments: { cell_number: 1 }
      }, {
        title: "Cell 2",
        action: :selected_cell,
        arguments: { cell_number: 2 }
      }]
    }]
  end

  def selected_cell(args={})
    if args[:cell_number] == 1
      open DetailScreen
    elsif args[:cell_number] == 2
      open OtherScreen
    end
  end
end

class DetailScreen < ProMotion::Screen
  title "Detail"

  def will_appear
    # Set up your UILabel and whatnot here
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Jamon. You answered two seperate posts for me. I'll definitely study cocoa touch. What do you suggest I read?  I'm assuming the docs...but, your text in the answer leaves off what you recommend.

Comment: I see your edit for what to read. Thanks a ton for your input!

Comment: You bet. If you have an iPhone or iPad, I would actually recommend the  iOS and Cocoa programming guides on iBook. They're free, lengthy, but worth looking at. Also, there are the Paul Hegarty lectures on iTunes U that can be of value. And look through the ProMotion tutorials and screencasts -- you'll pick up a lot of stuff there. Have fun with RubyMotion -- it's awesome!

Comment: Thanks again Jamon.  Sorry to post an unrelated comment...I wanted to make sure you saw it.  Im get 'ninitialized constant ProMotion::ScreenModule (NameError)' error after setting up (followed read me step by step) ProMotion and running rake.  I see you have dealt with that before...what might be causing it?

Comment: I'm going to dig into it again -- usually it's because RubyMotion isn't loading the files in the proper order.

Comment: Feel free to file a GitHub issue for these things too.